# Convert an AM/PM Time from String to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datetime-format

I have a table with a Time column that is a string [nvarchar(50)] with the following values.

```
5:34 AM
4:06 PM
7:14 PM
10:25 PM
2:12 AM
```

In my query, I am trying to order the various rows in ascending order but, because it is a string, it's ordering it in alphabetical order.

Is there a function I can use in the ORDER statement that will convert the string to a time or a datetime variable?
I have tried using the CAST and CONVERT with no luck.

```
CAST([Time] AS datetime)

Convert(nvarchar(50),[Time],101)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing time data in an `nvarchar(50)` column instead of a `time` column? (And also why `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`? Worried the clock will expand to include  `:00 PM`?)

Comment: This is due to the client. I have to workaround the fact that they are using nvarchar(50). I should have mentioned it in my initial post since this was my first thought as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT()` to sort by the right type (and avoid errors with garbage that got into your table):

```
DECLARE @BadDesign table(PoorChoice nvarchar(50));

INSERT @BadDesign(PoorChoice) VALUES
(N'5:34 AM'),
(N'4:06 PM'),
(N'7:14 PM'),
(N'10:25 PM'),
(N'2:12 AM'),
(N':00 PM');

SELECT PoorChoice, TRY_CONVERT(time, PoorChoice)
  FROM @BadDesign 
  ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(time, PoorChoice);
```

Output:

| PoorChoice | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| :00 PM | *null* |
| 2:12 AM | 02:12:00 |
| 5:34 AM | 05:34:00 |
| 4:06 PM | 16:06:00 |
| 7:14 PM | 19:14:00 |
| 10:25 PM | 22:25:00 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=298b8cc9d866b60842202e98b0cdd422)

Note that garbage data sorts on top. If you want to filter it out:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(time, PoorChoice) IS NULL
```

Comment: This was a hilarious response! TRY_CONVERT worked for me. I need to read up on how CONVERT and TRY_CONVERT work. Thank you!

Comment: Upvote for humour :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply try casting the string to a `TIME`.
If it's bad data the TRY_CAST returns NULL.

> ```
> declare @test table (timestring nvarchar(8));
> insert into @test values 
> ('5:34 AM'), 
> ('4:06 PM'), 
> ('7:14 PM'), 
> ('10:25 PM'), 
> ('2:12 AM');
>
> select *
> , try_cast(timestring as time(0)) 
> from @test;
> ```

> | timestring | (No column name) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 5:34 AM | 05:34:00 |
> | 4:06 PM | 16:06:00 |
> | 7:14 PM | 19:14:00 |
> | 10:25 PM | 22:25:00 |
> | 2:12 AM | 02:12:00 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2938d57217497083508490ba4bfdad8)*

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the time with a fixed date and a space, i.e. '01-01-1980 '.  Then you'll be able to cast to a datetime.